# How To Add a Transition style to Wordpress Comment Box?

Tags: css, comments

What I am looking for is to have the comment box slide down when a user clicks the reply button. I have tried several ways of adding my own CSS transition to the respond id and even did a height change to the element. I have also been playing around with the comment-reply.js file to add a custom class to the respond but nothing is working.

Comment: I have tried to add "jQuery(comm.parentNode).insertBefore( "#respond" ).hide().show('slow');" to replace "comm.parentNode.insertBefore( respond, comm.nextSibling );"  and now the box animates but is in the wrong place. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: okay I have gotten closer. I needed to have work with the form and not with the respond div. All I did was add a jquery line to toggle the animation.

"jQuery("#commentform").hide().show('slow');"

I hope this helps someone else who is looking to do something similar.